# How to Dynamically Create a Prefab from a Generated Room in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to Unity and game development, and I'm currently working on a project where I procedurally generate rooms. While I've made progress in generating these rooms based on certain parameters, I'm facing a challenge regarding how to organize and edit them efficiently. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to encapsulate these generated rooms within prefabs or another method that allows for easy editing and reuse in my project.

Here's a brief overview of my procedural room generation code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class RoomGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    
    [SerializeField] private Tilemap tilemap;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase floorSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase northWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase northeastWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase northwestWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase eastWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase westWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase southWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase southeastWallSprite;
    [SerializeField] private TileBase southwestWallSprite;

    public void CreateRoom(int width, int height, Vector2 offset){

        int yOffset = (int) offset.y;
        int xOffset = (int) offset.x;
        
        height += yOffset; 
        width += xOffset;

        for (int y = yOffset; y < height; y++) {
            
            for (int x = xOffset; x < width; x++) {
                
                Vector3Int spawnPosition = new Vector3Int(x, y, 0);
                Vector3Int tilePosition = tilemap.WorldToCell(spawnPosition);

                if(y == yOffset){

                    if(x == xOffset){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, southwestWallSprite);

                    }else if (x == width - 1){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, southeastWallSprite);
                    }else {
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, southWallSprite);
                    }
                } else if (y == height - 1){

                    if(x == xOffset){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, northwestWallSprite);
                    }else if (x == width - 1){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, northeastWallSprite);
                    }else {
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, northWallSprite);
                    }

                }else {
                        
                    if(x == xOffset){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, westWallSprite);
                    }else if (x == width - 1){
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, eastWallSprite);
                    }else {
                        tilemap.SetTile(tilePosition, floorSprite);
                    }
                }

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Now, my goal is to place each generated room inside a prefab, which will provide the flexibility to edit and reuse them later.

Additionally, if you have any suggestions for improving the efficiency or structure of my room generation code, I'm open to those as well.